# C++ add registry key

Tags: c++, registry

I have the following in my CPP code which adds the current program into startup. I'm trying to modify the code to add a different program to startup, say I want to add a key so that "C:\mytime.exe" runs on startup. Could you please help me modify the code?

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD pathLen = 0;

pathLen = GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
if (pathLen == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
HKEY newValue;
if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),
    &newValue) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return -1;
}
DWORD pathLenInBytes = pathLen * sizeof(*szPath);
if (RegSetValueEx(newValue,
    TEXT("My Program"),
    0,
    REG_SZ,
    (LPBYTE)szPath,
    pathLenInBytes) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    RegCloseKey(newValue);
    return -1;
}
RegCloseKey(newValue);
return TRUE;
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? Does this code work?

Comment: Why didn't you indent anything?

Comment: Does your application have the required permissions to alter that specific registry key?

Comment: Hi, this code works and "adds the current program name" into registry. I don't need to add current program name; rather I would like to add "c:\mytime.exe" into the registry. Hope I made the qn clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace this chunk of code:

```
pathLen = GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
if (pathLen == 0)
{
    return -1;
}
```

With this:

```
/* of course, use your own executable - make sure to not overflow the buffer! */
_tcscpy(szPath, _T("C:\\stackoverflow.exe"));
pathLen = _tcslen(szPath);
```

Comment: Thanks Nik! That's exactly what I was asking for.